# In Listview onItemClick() listener is not working?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have added an onItemClick() listener to a listview. The listener is not working.

Here is the code I am working with:`

```
MyBaseAdapter ma= new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList);
lvDetail.setAdapter(ma);
lvDetail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListData ld= myList.get(arg2);
        String des=ld.getDescription();
        Toast.makeText(context,"description"+des, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors? Log cat? Anything?

Comment: post your listview custom layout file

Comment: you can add `covertView.setOnClickListener()` in your adapter

Comment: Post your listView and custom layout xml file.

Comment: Please define 'not working'. Does it give error? or it gives wrong result?

Comment: Is there any clickable item in your list view row?.This may be consuming the click event

Comment: cAN U SHOW UR mYADAPTER CLASS??

Comment: it does not give any error.

Comment: So just check that in your xml file have you set **android:focusable = false** anywhere?

Comment: have you given the id to listview

Comment: Please give the complete code, this code doesn't show any mistakes on your part.

Comment: Maybe you should replace
`Toast.makeText(context,"description"+des, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
with
`Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"description"+des, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();`

Comment: add Log.v("test","test"); inside click event and check in logcat is that Log is displaying or not

Comment: may be you have added convertView.setOnClickListener in your adapter. Please remove it.

Comment: change Toast.makeText(context,"description"+des, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); to Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"description"+des, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: In listview.xml there is no issue. Post custom layout file and also Your custom adapter class

Comment: post the custom layout of listview

Comment: log is also not showing anything?

Comment: @irfan Are you using custom row layout for your list view? if yes please also post your row layout code here for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using custom adapter, please write listener inside getView of adapter on item of list and perform operation.